# How to import data from a file in opera widget

Tags: widget, opera

I am using opera widget to provide a link to my website on every page. How can i load data from external sources inside the widget?

I want to show data from sql database in the opera widget for desktop. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible to obtain data from a file in widget?

Please guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to access an external SQL database from a widget, however it is possible to read a local text file from a widget. The following simple example works for me on desktop with the latest Opera installed (11.52).

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://example.com/filereadertest" defaultlocale="en" width="400" height="500">
    <name>File Reader Test</name>
    <description>File Reader test widget</description>
    <author href="http://example.com/author/">Me</author>
    <feature name="http://xmlns.opera.com/fileio">
        <param name="folderhint" value="home" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body {
    background:#eee;
}
#output {
    width:98%;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Get the contents of a text file</p>
    <p><textarea id="output"></textarea></p>
    <p><button id="open">Open</button></p>
</div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    function openFile(evt) {
        opera.io.filesystem.browseForFile("test", "", openFileCallback)
    }

    function openFileCallback(file) {
        if (file) {
            fstream = file.open(file, "r");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
            output.value = "";
            while (!fstream.eof) {
                output.value += fstream.readLine("UTF-8");
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", openFile, false);

}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

More documentation is here:
[Widget File I/O API](http://dev.opera.com/libraries/fileio/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but You able to use a [HTML5 Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)  (SQLite integrated into brouser) in Your opera widgets